# How to apply Hungarian algorithm to highly unbalanced input (assume that input is in matrix form)

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have multiple jobs (for example 20) and I have very few workers (for example 2 or 3) then it is possible to match these two things by Hungarian algorithm because it is highly unbalanced input. If so how can I do this?

Comment: If you only have 2 or 3 workers and 20 jobs, what's wrong with a O(job^2) or O(jobs^3) brute force algorithm?

Comment: If you really want to use the Hungarian algorithm, you can do it by padding the problem with extra fake-workers that represent not-doing the job they are assigned.